# Facebook or Pinterest styled onclick load page as overlay content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In facebook feed or Pinterest gallery, when a user click on the content, `jQuery` will load the content and appended it to the current page as a modal (the url of browser will also changed according to `a.href`, even though there's no page reload). However, if the user launch a new page with the very same url, he is going to see a page with different layout (as opposed to the modal's) but the same content.

How do I accomplish this? (a click will load content onto a modal, while launch url as new window will display content on a new page with different layout)